# What is the real difference between the "head" and "header" tag?

Tags: html, header, head

### The Question

I've been coding for a while and realized that the head and header look exactly the same.  Are they the same, and what is the difference between them?  Does it make a difference?

After researching a bit I couldn't find much info on this, I may not have been digging deep enough.  The info I found was that the `<head>` tag came out since HTML 1 as the `<header>` tag came out in HTML5.  Is one more stable from the other?

### Summary

I would like to understand the difference between the two tags.  I would like a creditable/ or official source.  If you can please post the link of where you got the information.  A example of the code would be helpful too!  The main question I am asking is whether there is a difference and if so what difference is there.  Is there a benefit from one of them?  Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Duplicate sorry, didn't research enough.  I honestly ment to answer my own question, but I also did not see that there already was posts.  Sorry.

Comment: Also for future reference, just clearly state *what* you are asking for, no need to explain *how* it should be answered. Experienced users on this site already know how to post a quality answer :D

Comment: I'll take note.  Every time I ask a question here it always goes downhill.  Yet when I answer questions it goes uphill. :D

Comment: Asking a good question is certainly harder than composing a good answer.  Here are some tips that might help you with your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals the following:

**Head tag:**
The HTML `<head>` element provides general information (metadata) about the document, including its title and links to/definitions of scripts and style sheets. [(HTML MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)

**Header tag:**
The HTML `<header>` element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids. It may contain some heading elements but also other elements like a logo, wrapped section's header, a search form, and so on. [(HTML MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)

-

In other words; the head tag is used for document title, styling, scripts, etc.
Whereas the header tag is used for headers as seen in articles.

[image: Newspaper 'header'.]
*Newspaper 'header'*

**EDIT**: Updated reference, as *psuedocoder* mentioned, W3Schools is not always fully reliable.

Answer (score 9):

From W3C:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/head

"The `<head>` element represents a collection of metadata for the Document."

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header

"The `<header>` element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids."

The main difference is that the `<head>` element is for META data and the `<header>` element is for actual content.

Answer (score 4):

[The HTML `<head>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) is a container for metadata and links to scripts and stylesheets.

[The `<header>`tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) is a semantic container used to designate contents that is introductory or navigational in nature.