# CSS styling not applying to <head>

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS code that'll apply a background to the body tag but I won't apply the styling.

I have tried removing the background color and the heading tags within the `<head> </head>` tags, and nothing has happened

```
<head>
   <h1>My Website</h1>
</head>
<style>
   head {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background: #565656;
   }
</style>
```

I expected a gray top bar with the heading in it, but instead, it has ignored the heading CSS styling. This is what the website looks like: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/590377399489789984/600891092287750144/Screenshot_from_2019-07-16_23-25-52.png

Comment: I assume you are talking about header nav bar rather than document's head ?

Comment: No, I was talking about the document's head, can I not add CSS to it? @Tushar

Comment: Head doesn't do what you are expecting it to. `<head>` is the head element of the HTML file and provides things like metadata about the document. You are thinking of the `<header>` element. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919706/what-is-the-real-difference-between-the-head-and-header-tag

Comment: @Callum, I was using the wrong tag, and that was why it wasn't applying the styling. Thanks for showing me the difference!